# Continuous function with zero integral condition

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and suppose that $f(0) = 0$ and
$$\int_0^r f(x) \,dx \geq 0,\quad \forall r \in (0,1).$$
I want to known the behavior of $f$ near origin.
In that situation, can we conclude that there exists a $\delta > 0$ small enough such that
$f(x) \geq 0$ whenever $0 \leq x < \delta$?

Comment: I think not. $x\sin(1/x)$ should be a counterexaple

Comment: I think the function x sin(1/x) doesn't satisfy the zero integral condition... How do you think?

Comment: No, in fact knowing the integral is positive says nothing about the behavior near the origin

Comment: @Exodd However that does not satisfy the integral condition: changing variables by $u=1/x$ we get $$\int_{1/r}^{\infty} \frac{\sin u}{u^3}\text{d}u$$ which is negative for $r=1/\pi$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A counterexample.

Define $f_0$ continuous and piecewise linear:

- $f_0(x) = 0$ on $[0, 1/4]$,
- $f_0(x)= x-1/4$ on $[1/4, 1/2]$,
- $f_0(x)= 5/4-2x$ on $[1/2, 3/4]$,
- $f_0(x) = x-1$ on $[3/4, 1]$.

$\forall r \in [0, 1] \int_0^r f_0(x) dx \ge 0$, and $\int_0^1 f_0(x) dx = 0$.

Then define $f_1$:

- $f_1(x) = 1/4 f_0(4x)$ on $[0, 1/4]$
- $f_1(x) = f_0(x)$ on $[1/4, 1]$

$f_1$ is also continuous and piecewise linear. Its integral on $[0, r]$ is also $\ge 0$ $\forall r \in [0, 1]$, and the integral value is $0$ on $1/4$ and $1$.

Rince and repeat:

- $f_n(x) = 1/4 f_{n-1}(4x)$ on $[0, 1/4^n]$
- $f_n(x) = f_{n-1}(x)$ on $[1/4^n, 1]$

$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \forall r \in[0, 1], \int_0^r f_n(x) dx \ge 0$.

The $f_n$ converge uniformly, because:

- $\forall x \ge 1/4^{K+1}, \forall k \gt K, f_k(x) = f_K(x)$
- $\forall x \lt 1/4^{K+1}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, |f_n(x)| \le 1/4^{K+2}$

Hence the limit function $f$ is continuous and $\forall r \in [0, 1], \int_0^r f(x) dx \ge 0$.

But $f$ has strictly negative values as close as $0$ as we want.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. This zigzag function is nice!

Comment: You're welcome. The only missing thing is a diagram; I was too lazy to draw one :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let $g$ be any continuous function satisfying the following conditions:

- $\mathrm{supp}\, g\subset [0,1]$, i.e. $g(x)=0$ for $x$ outside $[0,1]$;
- $g$ changes sign (has positive and negative values;
- $\int_0^t g(x)dx>0$ for all $t>0$.

Now define $f\colon [0,1]\to\Bbb R$ by the formula
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{2^n} g\left(2^{n}x-1\right).$$

Observe that if $g\left(2^{n}x-1\right)\neq 0$ then $0<2^{n}x-1<1$, so $2^{-n}<x<2^{1-n}$, that is supports of the summands are disjoint. This implies that $f$ is negative for points arbitrarily close to 0. Nevertheless, for $r>0$ we have
$$\int_0^rf(x)dx>0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$f_n(x)=\sin(2^{n+1}\pi x)$$ which clearly satisfies both conditions (the integral one by simmetry) and let $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(2^{n+1}\pi x)}{2^n}\mathbf{1}_{[1/2^n,\, 2/2^n]}.$$ Then the series is uniformly convergent by Weierstrass criterion as $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{|\sin(2^{n+1} \pi x)|}{2^n}\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}=1$$ thus the integral condition is still satisfied as we can integrate term by term. Since for each $n$ we know that $f_n<0$ in the second half of $(1/2^n,\, 2/2^n)$, we conclude that such a $\delta$ does not exist.

[image: Graph of f(x)]

Comment: The limit of $g_n$ is the function that is null on $[0, 1]$, so it has no negative value.

Comment: Oh oops, I forgot to take the series, now I fixed it.